# Media player subtitles in WPF - Part 1 Processing and storing

Tags: c#, file-system, wpf, stream

I'm writing a media player in WPF and since movies are playable, subtitles are a must.

Here's what it looks like so far:

[image]

On the left is the settings tab, in the middle is the actual player and on the right is the playlist.

I feel like asking 1 big question wont be as beneficial as breaking it down into 3 questions, where each one covers a specific aspect of the system. This specific one is the most fundamental - reading and storing the subtitle segments' information.

[Part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/192687/98577)

There are a lot of supporting classes involved and while it would be nice to get them reviewed as well, I'd like to put the main focus on the subtitle related classes.

---

I started by creating the subtitle model classes. Subtitles have a starting/end point and some content. The first characteristic seems like something I might need to use in the future so I decided to write an interface for it:

```
public interface IInterval<T> : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
    where T : IInterval<T>
{
    TimeSpan Start { get; }
    TimeSpan End { get; }
}
```

And later inherited by the concrete `SubtitleInterval`:

```
[Serializable]
public class SubtitleInterval : IInterval<SubtitleInterval>
{
    public TimeSpan Start { get; }
    public TimeSpan End { get; }

    public TimeSpan Duration => End.Subtract(Start);

    public SubtitleInterval(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Start} --> {End}";
    }

    #region Implementation of IEquatable<SubtitleInterval>

    public bool Equals(SubtitleInterval other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Start.Equals(other.Start) && End.Equals(other.End);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((SubtitleInterval)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Start.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ End.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IComparable<SubtitleInterval>

    public int CompareTo(SubtitleInterval other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return 0;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return 1;
        var startComparison = Start.CompareTo(other.Start);
        if (startComparison != 0) return startComparison;
        return End.CompareTo(other.End);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

Next is the actual Model for the subtitles, it consists mainly of 2 properties - Interval and Content, `IEquatable<>` and `IComparable<>` are implemented as well:

```
[Serializable]
public class SubtitleSegment : IEquatable<SubtitleSegment>, IComparable<SubtitleSegment>
{
    public SubtitleInterval Interval { get; }

    public string Content { get; }

    public SubtitleSegment([NotNull] SubtitleInterval subtitleInterval, string content)
    {
        Interval = subtitleInterval ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subtitleInterval));
        Content = content;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Interval} {Environment.NewLine} {Content}";
    }

    #region IEquatable implementation

    public bool Equals(SubtitleSegment other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Equals(Interval, other.Interval) && string.Equals(Content, other.Content);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((SubtitleSegment)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((Interval != null ? Interval.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^
                   (Content != null ? Content.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparable implementation

    public int CompareTo(SubtitleSegment other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return 0;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return 1;
        return Interval.CompareTo(Interval);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

I also wanted *.srt* files that share the same name with the movie, located in the current played movie's directory or any sub-directory, to be automatically played, instead of manually inserting them.

I also have a setting changeable by the user, which allows for preferred language of the automatically detected subtitles to be set. This is usually indicated by a suffix in the file's name e.g: *MovieName.en.srt*, *MovieName.bg.srt*.. In case there is no file with the corresponding suffix the first one that doesn't have any will be selected.

For that purpose I added the `SubtitleDetector` static class:

```
public static class SubtitleDetector
{
    public static FileInformation DetectSubtitles(
        [NotNull] MediaFileInformation file,
        string preferedSubtitleLanguage)
    {
        if (file == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(file));

        var availableSubtitles =
            file.FileInfo.Directory.GetFiles($"*{Settings.SubtitleExtensionString}", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(preferedSubtitleLanguage))
        {
            if (preferedSubtitleLanguage[0] != '.')
            {
                preferedSubtitleLanguage = preferedSubtitleLanguage.Insert(0, ".");
            }

            var preferedLanguageSubtitle = availableSubtitles
                .Where(s => s.Name.Contains(
                    $"{preferedSubtitleLanguage}{Settings.SubtitleExtensionString}"))
                .FirstOrDefault(info => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(info.Name) ==
                                        $"{file.FileName}{preferedSubtitleLanguage}");

            if (preferedLanguageSubtitle != null)
            {
                return new FileInformation(preferedLanguageSubtitle.FullName);
            }
        }

        return availableSubtitles.Where(subs => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(subs.Name) == file.FileName)
            .Select(subs => new FileInformation(subs.FullName)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

---

Next I needed some way to read the actual content of the *.srt* file, first I started by inspecting the way they are written and luckily the format was rather simple:

```
Start --> End
Content

Start --> End
Content

00:00:00,012 --> 00:00:02,244
Content1

00:00:09:368 --> 00:00:12,538
Content2
```

There are some extra rules to where exactly you can put `:`, `,` or `.` when indicating the interval of the subtitles, but I wont dig too much into that.

```
public sealed class SubtitleReader
{
    public Encoding Encoding { get; }

    public SubtitleReader([NotNull] Encoding encoding)
    {
        Encoding = encoding ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encoding));
    }

    public CircularList<SubtitleSegment> ExtractSubtitles([NotNull] string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

        var subtitles = new CircularList<SubtitleSegment>();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding))
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var lines = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (TryParseSubtitleInterval(lines[i], out var interval))
                {
                    var content = ExtractCurrentSubtitleContent(i, lines);
                    subtitles.Add(new SubtitleSegment(interval, content));
                }
            }
        }
        return subtitles.OrderBy(s => s).ToCircularList();
    }

    private string ExtractCurrentSubtitleContent(int startIndex, string[] lines)
    {
        var subtitleContent = new StringBuilder();
        int endIndex = Array.IndexOf(lines, string.Empty, startIndex);
        for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++)
        {
            subtitleContent.AppendLine(lines[i].Trim(' '));
        }
        return subtitleContent.ToString();
    }

    private bool TryParseSubtitleInterval(string input, out SubtitleInterval interval)
    {
        interval = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var segments = input.Split(new[] { Settings.SubtitleSeparationString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (segments.Length != 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        segments = segments.Select(s => s.Trim(' ').Replace(',', '.').Replace('.', ':')).ToArray();
        if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(segments[0], Settings.GetTimeSpanStringFormats(), DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
                out var start) &&
            TimeSpan.TryParseExact(segments[1], Settings.GetTimeSpanStringFormats(), DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
                out var end) &&
            start < end)
        {
            interval = new SubtitleInterval(start, end);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Where the supplied TimeSpanFormats are as follows:

```
private static readonly string[] _timeSpanStringFormats =
{
    @"h\:m\:s",
    @"h\:m\:s\:f",
    @"h\:m\:s\:ff",
    @"h\:m\:s\:fff",
    @"h\:m\:ss",
    @"h\:m\:ss\:f",
    @"h\:m\:ss\:ff",
    @"h\:m\:ss\:fff",
    @"h\:mm\:s",
    @"h\:mm\:s\:f",
    @"h\:mm\:s\:ff",
    @"h\:mm\:s\:fff",
    @"h\:mm\:ss",
    @"h\:mm\:ss\:f",
    @"h\:mm\:ss\:ff",
    @"h\:mm\:ss\:fff",
    @"hh\:m\:s",
    @"hh\:m\:s\:f",
    @"hh\:m\:s\:ff",
    @"hh\:m\:s\:fff",
    @"hh\:m\:ss",
    @"hh\:m\:ss\:f",
    @"hh\:m\:ss\:ff",
    @"hh\:m\:ss\:fff",
    @"hh\:mm\:s",
    @"hh\:mm\:s\:f",
    @"hh\:mm\:s\:ff",
    @"hh\:mm\:s\:fff",
    @"hh\:mm\:ss",
    @"hh\:mm\:ss\:f",
    @"hh\:mm\:ss\:ff",
    @"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff",
};
```

And the `CircularList<>` implementation:

```
public interface ICircularList<T> : IList<T>
{
    T Next { get; }
    T Previous { get; }
    T MoveNext();
    T MovePrevious();
    T Current { get; }
    void SetCurrent(int currentIndex);
    void Reset();
}

public class CircularList<T> : ICircularList<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _elements = new List<T>();

    private int _lastUsedElementIndex;

    public CircularList(IEnumerable<T> collection, int startingIterableIndex = 0)
    {
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            _elements.Add(item);
        }
        _lastUsedElementIndex = startingIterableIndex;
    }

    public CircularList()
    {
    }

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _elements.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of ICollection<T>

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _elements.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _elements.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _elements.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _elements.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return _elements.Remove(item);
    }

    public int Count => _elements.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IList<T>
    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _elements.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        _elements.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _elements.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => _elements[index];
        set => _elements[index] = value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of ICircularList<T>

    public T Next => _lastUsedElementIndex + 1 >= _elements.Count
        ? _elements[0]
        : _elements[_lastUsedElementIndex + 1];

    public T Previous => _lastUsedElementIndex - 1 < 0
        ? _elements[_elements.Count - 1]
        : _elements[_lastUsedElementIndex - 1];

    public T MoveNext()
    {
        int temp = _lastUsedElementIndex;
        _lastUsedElementIndex++;
        if (_lastUsedElementIndex >= _elements.Count)
        {
            _lastUsedElementIndex = 0;
        }
        return _elements[temp];
    }

    public T MovePrevious()
    {
        int temp = _lastUsedElementIndex;
        _lastUsedElementIndex--;
        if (_lastUsedElementIndex < 0)
        {
            _lastUsedElementIndex = _elements.Count - 1;
        }
        return _elements[temp];
    }

    public T Current => _elements.Count == 0
        ? default(T)
        : _elements[_lastUsedElementIndex];

    public void SetCurrent(int currentIndex)
    {
        _lastUsedElementIndex = currentIndex;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _lastUsedElementIndex = 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`FileInformation` classes:

```
public interface IFileInformation
{
    string FileName { get; }
    FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    Uri Uri { get; }
}

public class FileInformation : IFileInformation, IEquatable<FileInformation>
{
    public string FileName { get; }
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    public Uri Uri { get; }

    public FileInformation([NotNull] string filePath)
        : this(new Uri(filePath))
    {
    }

    public FileInformation([NotNull] Uri fileUri)
    {
        Uri = fileUri ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileUri));
        FileInfo = new FileInfo(fileUri.OriginalString);
        FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileInfo.Name);
    }

    #region Equality members

    public bool Equals(FileInformation other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(FileName, other.FileName) && Equals(FileInfo, other.FileInfo) && Equals(Uri, other.Uri);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((FileInformation)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (FileName != null ? FileName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (FileInfo != null ? FileInfo.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Uri != null ? Uri.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
public class MediaFileInformation : DependencyObject, IFileInformation, INotifyPropertyChanged, IEquatable<MediaFileInformation>
{
    public TimeSpan FileLength { get; }
    public string FileName { get; }
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    public Uri Uri { get; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPlayingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsPlaying), typeof(bool), typeof(MediaFileInformation),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPlayingProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MediaFileInformation([NotNull] string filePath)
        : this(new Uri(filePath))
    {
    }

    public MediaFileInformation([NotNull] Uri fileUri)
    {
        Uri = fileUri ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileUri));
        FileInfo = new FileInfo(fileUri.OriginalString);
        FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileInfo.Name);
        FileLength = FileInfo.GetFileDuration();
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Equality members

    public bool Equals(MediaFileInformation other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return FileLength.Equals(other.FileLength) && string.Equals(FileName, other.FileName) &&
               Equals(FileInfo, other.FileInfo) && Equals(Uri, other.Uri);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: @t3chb0t added a screenshot

Comment: This is nice! :-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think can be improved...

---

The `bool Equals(object obj)` method of the `SubtitleInterval` does not need to repeat the implementation of its strongly typed counterpart. You could use the new `is` operator and redirect it like this:

```
return obj is SubtitleInterval si && Equals(si);
```

You can do the same with the `SubtitleSegment` and `FileInformation` classes.

---

Instead of the old `?:`

> ```
> Interval != null ? Interval.GetHashCode() : 0
> ```

you can now use a combination of the new `?` and `??` and make it simpler:

```
Interval?.GetHashCode() ?? 0
```

---

You seem to like negative conditions...

> ```
> if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(preferedSubtitleLanguage))
> ```

and

> ```
> if (preferedSubtitleLanguage[0] != '.')
> ```

and

> ```
> if (preferedLanguageSubtitle != null)
> ```

I find that positive ones are easier to understand so I suggest trying to flip them where possible and use early returns that would also contribute to less nesting.

---

> ```
> if (preferedSubtitleLanguage[0] != '.')
> ```

This conditios is too magical. You should introduce a helper variable, and/or use a `const` explaining the `'.'`, and/or use a `const` for the `0` index explaining its purpose.

---

> ```
> if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(segments[0], Settings.GetTimeSpanStringFormats(), DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
>                 out var start) &&
>             TimeSpan.TryParseExact(segments[1], Settings.GetTimeSpanStringFormats(), DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
>                 out var end) &&
>             start < end)
> ```

The poor `if` :-( I wouldn't put so much code in there, it gets ugly. A new helper method would be cleaner. In fact, the `SubtitleInterval` could implement a `TryParse` method.

---

Did you really write all the `_timeSpanStringFormats` by hand? I'm lazy, I'd write some code to generate it :-)

---

> ```
> public CircularList(IEnumerable<T> collection, int startingIterableIndex = 0)
> {
>     foreach (T item in collection)
>     {
>         _elements.Add(item);
>     }
>     _lastUsedElementIndex = startingIterableIndex;
> }
> ```

Throw a way the `foreach`. `List<T>` has a constructor that takes a collection.

---

I would try to come up with a better name for the `FileInformation` type. With something more domain related. Maybe `SubtitleFile` etc. There is already a `FileInfo` and creating another, similar type, makes it confusing.

---

What else I think...

Other than these couple of nitpicks this code is very well structured and pretty clean. Good job!