# Media player subtitles in WPF - Part 2 Handlers and notifications

Tags: c#, event-handling, wpf

This is a continuation of [Part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192685/media-player-subtitles-in-wpf-part-1-processing-and-storing).

In this question I will present you with a single class which is the most crucial component of the whole system, it's responsible for firing notifications whenever a subtitle must be shown or hidden. The notifications are later consumed by a ViewModel which than notifies it's View, but I will keep that part for the next question.

```
public sealed class SubtitleHandler : ICustomObservable<MediaEventArgs<SubtitlesEventType>>
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly AsyncManualResetEvent _manualResetEventAsync = new AsyncManualResetEvent();

    private CircularList<SubtitleSegment> _subtitles;
    private readonly HashSet<SubtitleSegment> _currentlyShownSubtitles = new HashSet<SubtitleSegment>();

    private readonly IntermissionTimer _subtitleDisplayTracker;

    private readonly Encoding _encoding;

    private IMediaControlsViewModel _providerControls;

    private MediaObservableMap<SubscriptionEventType> _subtitlesProviderMap;
    private MediaObservableMap<MediaElementEventType> _mediaElementProviderMap;
    private MediaObservableMap<MediaControlEventType> _mediaControlsProviderMap;
    private ObservableMap<bool, FileManagerEventArgs<FileInformation>> _fileManagerMap;

    private readonly MultipleProvidersCache _multipleProvidersCache = new MultipleProvidersCache();

    private readonly SingleComparer<TimeSpan> _resyncComparer =
        new SingleComparer<TimeSpan>((span, subtitleInterval) => span > subtitleInterval);

    private static readonly object _padLock = new object();

    public SubtitleHandler([NotNull] Encoding encoding, [NotNull] ISubtitlesViewModel provider)
    {
        if (provider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));

        _encoding = encoding ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encoding));
        _subtitleDisplayTracker = new IntermissionTimer();
        _subtitleDisplayTracker.Tick += SubtitleDisplayTracker_OnTick;
        InitializeMaps();
        ConfigureNotifications(provider);
    }

    private void InitializeMaps()
    {
        _subtitlesProviderMap = new MediaObservableMap<SubscriptionEventType>((map, args) => args.EventType)
        {
            {SubscriptionEventType.MediaAttached,
                (sender, args) => AttachMediaElement((IMediaElementViewModel) args.AdditionalInfo)
            },
            {SubscriptionEventType.MediaDetached, (sender, args) => DetachMediaElement()},
        };

        _mediaElementProviderMap = new MediaObservableMap<MediaElementEventType>((map, args) => args.EventType)
        {
            {MediaElementEventType.Started, (sender, args) => TryBegin((MediaFileInformation) args.AdditionalInfo)},
            {MediaElementEventType.Ended, (sender, args) => Stop()}
        };

        _mediaControlsProviderMap = new MediaObservableMap<MediaControlEventType>(
            (map, args) => args.EventType, 
            (map, type) => _subtitles != null)
        {
            {MediaControlEventType.FastForwardClick, Skip},
            {MediaControlEventType.RewindClick, Skip},
            {MediaControlEventType.PauseClick, (sender, args) => Pause()},
            {MediaControlEventType.PlayClick, (sender, args) => Resume()},
            {MediaControlEventType.StopClick, (sender, args) => Stop()},
            {MediaControlEventType.PositionSliderDragStarted, (sender, args) =>
                {
                    ForceHidingAllSubtitles();
                    Pause();
                }
            },
            {
                MediaControlEventType.PositionSliderDragCompleted,
                async (sender, args) => await ResyncAndResumeAsync((TimeSpan) args.AdditionalInfo)
            }
        };

        _fileManagerMap = new ObservableMap<bool, FileManagerEventArgs<FileInformation>>(
            (map, args) => args.SelectedFiles.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            {
                true, (sender, args) => Begin(args.SelectedFiles.First(),
                    _providerControls?.CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position ?? default(TimeSpan))
            }
        };
    }

    private async void Skip(object sender, MediaEventArgs<MediaControlEventType> args)
    {
        var time = (TimeSpan) args.AdditionalInfo;
        if (_subtitleDisplayTracker.IsEnabled)
        {
            await ResyncAndResumeAsync(time);
        }
        else
        {
            Resync(time);
        }
    }

    private void ConfigureNotifications(ISubtitlesViewModel subtitlesProvider)
    {
        _multipleProvidersCache.AddProvider(subtitlesProvider, _subtitlesProviderMap);
        _multipleProvidersCache.AddProvider(FileManager<FileInformation>.Instance, _fileManagerMap);
    }

    private void AttachMediaElement(IMediaElementViewModel mediaElementProvider)
    {
        _providerControls = mediaElementProvider.CurentControls;
        _multipleProvidersCache.AddProvider(mediaElementProvider, _mediaElementProviderMap);
        _multipleProvidersCache.AddProvider(_providerControls, _mediaControlsProviderMap);
    }

    private void DetachMediaElement()
    {
        _multipleProvidersCache.RemoveProvider<IMediaElementViewModel, MediaEventArgs<MediaElementEventType>>();
        _multipleProvidersCache.RemoveProvider<IMediaControlsViewModel, MediaEventArgs<MediaControlEventType>>();
        _providerControls = null;
        ForceHidingAllSubtitles();
    }

    private async void SubtitleDisplayTracker_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lastSubtitle = _subtitles.Current;
        _subtitles.MoveNext();
        _subtitleDisplayTracker.Interval = _subtitles.Current.Interval.Start -
                                           lastSubtitle.Interval.Start;
        await ResyncWithPlayerAsync(lastSubtitle.Interval);
        await ShowSubtitleAsync(lastSubtitle, lastSubtitle.Interval.Duration);
    }

    private async Task ResyncWithPlayerAsync(SubtitleInterval currentInterval)
    {
        var result = currentInterval.Start.Subtract(_providerControls.CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position);
        var tolerance = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        if (result > tolerance)
        {
            //current is ahead
            await Task.Delay(result, _cancellationToken.Token).ContinueWith(_ => { });
        }
    }

    private void TryBegin(MediaFileInformation file)
    {
        if (Settings.DetectSubtitlesAutomatically)
        {
            var localSubs = SubtitleDetector.DetectSubtitles(file, Settings.PreferedSubtitleLanguage);
            if (localSubs != null)
            {
                Begin(localSubs, TimeSpan.Zero);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Begin(IFileInformation subtitleFile, TimeSpan startTime)
    {
        if (_subtitles != null)
        {
            _subtitleDisplayTracker.Stop();
        }
        _subtitles = new SubtitleReader(_encoding).ExtractSubtitles(subtitleFile.Uri.OriginalString);
        Resync(startTime);
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _manualResetEventAsync.Set();
        _subtitleDisplayTracker.Start();
    }

    private void Pause()
    {
        _subtitleDisplayTracker.Pause();
        _manualResetEventAsync.Reset();
        _cancellationToken.Cancel();
    }

    private void Resume()
    {
        _manualResetEventAsync.Set();
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _subtitleDisplayTracker.Resume();
    }

    private void Resync(TimeSpan time)
    {
        ForceHidingAllSubtitles();
        _resyncComparer.TargetValue = time;
        var targetIndex =
            _subtitles.DuplicateBinarySearch(_resyncComparer, segment => segment.Interval.End);
        var targetSubs = _subtitles[targetIndex];

        _subtitles.SetCurrent(targetIndex);
        if (time > targetSubs.Interval.Start)
        {
            _subtitles.SetCurrent(targetIndex + 1);
#pragma warning disable 4014
            ShowSubtitleAsync(targetSubs, targetSubs.Interval.End.Subtract(time));
#pragma warning restore 4014
        }
        _subtitleDisplayTracker.Interval = _subtitles.Current.Interval.Start.Subtract(time);
    }

    private async Task ResyncAndResumeAsync(TimeSpan span)
    {
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    lock (_padLock)
                    {
                        Resync(span);
                    }
                },
                _cancellationToken.Token,
                TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously,
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    Resume();
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private void Stop()
    {
        _subtitleDisplayTracker.Stop();
        Resync(TimeSpan.Zero);
    }

    private async Task ShowSubtitleAsync(SubtitleSegment subtitle, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        OnDisplaySubtitle(subtitle);
        _currentlyShownSubtitles.Add(subtitle);

        await ScheduleSubtitleHidingAsync(subtitle, duration);
    }

    private async Task ScheduleSubtitleHidingAsync(SubtitleSegment subtitle, TimeSpan span)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;

        await Task.Delay(span, _cancellationToken.Token)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    OnHideSubtitle(subtitle);
                    _currentlyShownSubtitles.Remove(subtitle);
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        var leftTime = span.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Ticks));
        if (leftTime > TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
        {
            await _manualResetEventAsync.WaitAsync();
            await ScheduleSubtitleHidingAsync(subtitle, leftTime);
        }
    }

    private void ForceHidingAllSubtitles()
    {
        if (_currentlyShownSubtitles.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        _cancellationToken.Cancel(false);
        _manualResetEventAsync.Reset();
        lock (_padLock)
        {
            foreach (var currentlyShownSubtitle in _currentlyShownSubtitles)
            {
                OnHideSubtitle(currentlyShownSubtitle);
            }
            _currentlyShownSubtitles.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void OnHideSubtitle(SubtitleSegment subtitle)
    {
        OnNotify(SubtitlesEventType.Hide, subtitle);
    }

    private void OnDisplaySubtitle(SubtitleSegment subtitle)
    {
        OnNotify(SubtitlesEventType.Display, subtitle);
    }

    #region Implementation of ICustomObservable<MediaEventArgs<SubtitlesEventType>>

    public event EventHandler<MediaEventArgs<SubtitlesEventType>> Notify;

    private void OnNotify(SubtitlesEventType eventType, object additionalInfo = null)
    {
        Notify?.Invoke(this, new MediaEventArgs<SubtitlesEventType>(eventType, additionalInfo));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The media player has functionality for pausing/resuming, fast forward/rewind, dragging the slider, jumping through the slider and stopping the file, if there is a subtitle track running, the `SubtitleHandler` must react correspondingly.

There is an internal `IntermissionTimer` which keeps track of when the next subtitle should be shown, it allows `Pause/Resume` behaviour and it's implemented as follows:

```
public class IntermissionTimer : DispatcherTimer
{
    protected MulticastDelegate _tickEventHandlers;
    protected MulticastDelegate TickEventHandlers =>
        _tickEventHandlers ?? (_tickEventHandlers = (MulticastDelegate)typeof(DispatcherTimer)
            .GetField("Tick", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            ?.GetValue(this));

    protected CancellationTokenSource _cancellationToken;

    protected readonly Stopwatch _internalTickCounter;
    protected Stopwatch _intervalTickedTime;

    public TimeSpan Elapsed => _internalTickCounter.Elapsed;

    public new TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get => base.Interval;
        set
        {
            base.Interval = value;
            _cancellationToken.Cancel();
            _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _intervalTickedTime.Reset();
            if (_internalTickCounter.IsRunning)
            {
                Start();
            }
        }
    }

    public IntermissionTimer()
    {
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _internalTickCounter = new Stopwatch();
        _intervalTickedTime = new Stopwatch();

        Tick += IntermissionTimer_Tick;
    }

    protected virtual void IntermissionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == this)
        {
            _intervalTickedTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }
    }

    public new virtual void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        _internalTickCounter.Start();
        _intervalTickedTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public new virtual void Stop()
    {
        base.Stop();
        _internalTickCounter.Reset();
        _intervalTickedTime.Reset();
        _cancellationToken.Cancel();
    }

    public virtual void Pause()
    {
        _cancellationToken.Cancel();
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        base.Stop();
        _internalTickCounter.Stop();
        _intervalTickedTime.Stop();
    }

    public virtual void Resume()
    {
        if (!_internalTickCounter.IsRunning)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                _internalTickCounter.Start();
                _intervalTickedTime.Start();
                var scheduledIntermissionTime =
                    Math.Abs((int) (Interval - _intervalTickedTime.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds);
                await Task.Delay(scheduledIntermissionTime, _cancellationToken.Token)
                    .ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                        {
                            foreach (var handler in TickEventHandlers.GetInvocationList())
                            {
                                handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, new object[] {this, EventArgs.Empty});
                            }
                            Start();
                        }
                    }, TaskScheduler.Default);
                _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

Notifications when a specific action has occurred (pause, resume, etc.) are handled by the `MultipleProvidersCache` class and are being sent by multiple providers:

```
internal class MultipleProvidersCache
{
    protected readonly ProviderActionCache<EventHandler<object>> _notificationsCache =
        new ProviderActionCache<EventHandler<object>>();

    protected readonly ProviderActionCache<Action> _providerUnsubscriberCache = new ProviderActionCache<Action>();

    internal virtual void AddProvider<T, TArgs>(
        [NotNull] ICustomObservable<TArgs> provider,
        [NotNull] ObservableMap<T, TArgs> map)
        where TArgs : EventArgs
    {
        if (provider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));
        if (map == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(map));

        var providerType = provider.GetType();
        _notificationsCache.Add<TArgs>(providerType, (sender, args) =>
        {
            var unboxedArgs = (TArgs) args;
            if (map.TryGetHandler(unboxedArgs, out var handler))
            {
                handler.Invoke(sender, unboxedArgs);
            }
        });
        void NotifierDelegate(object sender, TArgs args) => Provider_OnNotify(sender, args, providerType);
        provider.Notify += NotifierDelegate;
        _providerUnsubscriberCache.Add<TArgs>(providerType, () => provider.Notify -= NotifierDelegate);
    }

    internal virtual bool RemoveProvider<TProvider, TArgs>()
        where TArgs : EventArgs
        where TProvider : ICustomObservable<TArgs>
    {
        return RemoveProviderImpl<TArgs>(typeof(TProvider));
    }

    protected virtual bool RemoveProviderImpl<TArgs>([NotNull] Type providerType)
        where TArgs : EventArgs
    {
        if (providerType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providerType));

        if (_notificationsCache.RemoveAction<TArgs>(providerType))
        {
            _providerUnsubscriberCache.GetAction<TArgs>(providerType).Invoke();
            _providerUnsubscriberCache.RemoveAction<TArgs>(providerType);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected virtual void Provider_OnNotify<TArgs>(object sender, TArgs e, Type providerType)
        where TArgs : EventArgs
    {
        if (_notificationsCache.TryGetAction<TArgs>(providerType, out var action))
        {
            action.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }

    protected sealed class ProviderActionCache<TAction> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, Dictionary<Type, TAction>>>
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, TAction>> _dictionary;

        internal ProviderActionCache()
        {
            _dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, TAction>>();
        }

        internal void Add<TArgs>([NotNull] Type key, [NotNull] TAction value)
            where TArgs : EventArgs
        {
            if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

            if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var values))
            {
                values.Add(typeof(TArgs), value);
            }
            else
            {
                _dictionary.Add(key, new Dictionary<Type, TAction> { [typeof(TArgs)] = value });
            }
        }

        internal bool RemoveProvider([NotNull] Type providerType)
        {
            if (providerType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providerType));

            return _dictionary.Remove(providerType);
        }

        internal bool RemoveAction<TArgs>([NotNull] Type providerType)
            where TArgs : EventArgs
        {
            if (providerType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providerType));

            return _dictionary.TryGetValue(providerType, out var values) && values.Remove(typeof(TArgs));
        }

        internal bool TryGetProvider([NotNull] Type providerType, out Dictionary<Type, TAction> values)
        {
            if (providerType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providerType));

            return _dictionary.TryGetValue(providerType, out values);
        }

        internal bool TryGetAction<TArgs>([NotNull] Type providerType, out TAction action)
            where TArgs : EventArgs
        {
            if (providerType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providerType));

            if (TryGetProvider(providerType, out var value))
            {
                action = value[typeof(TArgs)];
                return true;
            }
            action = default(TAction);
            return false;
        }

        internal TAction GetAction<TArgs>([NotNull] Type providerType)
            where TArgs : EventArgs
        {
            if (providerType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providerType));

            return _dictionary[providerType][typeof(TArgs)];
        }

        internal Dictionary<Type, TAction> GetProvider([NotNull] Type providerType)
        {
            if (providerType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providerType));

            return _dictionary[providerType];
        }

        #region Implementation of IEnumerable

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<Type, Dictionary<Type, TAction>>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _dictionary.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Also the `ObservableMap<,>` and `MediaObservableMap<,>`

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper to avoid long dictionary declarations when used for <see cref="ICustomObservable{TArgs}"/>> mapping.
/// </summary>
internal class ObservableMap<T, TArgs> : Dictionary<T, EventHandler<TArgs>>
{
    protected Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, T, bool> _predicate;
    protected Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, TArgs, T> _selector;

    /// <param name="values">Values to populate into the <see cref="ObservableMap{T,TArgs}"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="selector">Used for complex index selection.</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">If the condition is false <see cref="TryGetHandler(T, out EventHandler{TArgs})"/> 
    /// will not look for entry and instead will return false.</param>
    internal ObservableMap(
        [NotNull] IDictionary<T, EventHandler<TArgs>> values,
        [NotNull] Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, TArgs, T> selector,
        [NotNull]  Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, T, bool> predicate)
        : this(values, selector)
    {
        _predicate = predicate ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
    }

    /// <param name="values">Values to populate into the <see cref="ObservableMap{T,TArgs}"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="selector">Used for complex index selection.</param>
    internal ObservableMap(
        [NotNull]   IDictionary<T, EventHandler<TArgs>> values,
        [NotNull]  Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, TArgs, T> selector)
        : base(values)
    {
        _selector = selector ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
    }

    /// <param name="selector">Used for complex index selection.</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">If the condition is false <see cref="TryGetHandler(T, out EventHandler{TArgs})"/> 
    /// will not look for entry and instead will return false.</param>
    internal ObservableMap(
        [NotNull]   Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, TArgs, T> selector,
        [NotNull]   Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, T, bool> predicate)
        : this(selector)
    {
        _predicate = predicate ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
    }

    /// <param name="selector">Used for complex index selection.</param>
    internal ObservableMap(
        [NotNull]  Func<ObservableMap<T, TArgs>, TArgs, T> selector)
    {
        _selector = selector ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
    }

    internal virtual bool TryGetHandler([NotNull] TArgs args, out EventHandler<TArgs> handler)
    {
        if(args == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));
        return TryGetHandler(_selector.Invoke(this, args), out handler);
    }

    internal virtual bool TryGetHandler([NotNull] T key, out EventHandler<TArgs> handler)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));

        if (_predicate?.Invoke(this, key) == false)
        {
            handler = null;
            return false;
        }
        return TryGetValue(key, out handler);
    }

    internal new EventHandler<TArgs> this[T key] => base[key];
}

internal class MediaObservableMap<TEnumeration> : ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>
    where TEnumeration : Enumeration<TEnumeration>
{
    internal MediaObservableMap(
        IDictionary<TEnumeration, EventHandler<MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>> values,
        Func<ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>, TEnumeration> selector,
        Func<ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>, TEnumeration, bool> predicate)
        : base(values, selector, predicate)
    {
    }

    internal MediaObservableMap(
        IDictionary<TEnumeration, EventHandler<MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>> values,
        Func<ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>, TEnumeration> selector)
        : base(values, selector)
    {
    }

    internal MediaObservableMap(
        Func<ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>, TEnumeration> selector, 
        Func<ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>, TEnumeration, bool> predicate)
        : base(selector, predicate)
    {
    }

    internal MediaObservableMap(
        Func<ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>, TEnumeration> selector) 
        : base(selector)
    {
    }
}
```

I have not included some specific classes and interfaces, because their implementations are not important for this question, but I will give a brief description of what they are supposed to do:

The types: `SubscriptionEventType`, `MediaElementEventType` and `MediaControlEventType` are all custom `Enumeration` classes, for their implementation please refer to [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/191019/98577)

The type `ICustomObservable<>` is very simple it has only 1 event `Notify`, which is used to notify subscribers.

The type `SingleComparer<>` is only used for the Binary Search used in the `Resync` method, it allows for a complex search to be performed, in this case it returns the first item matching the predicate.

All of the `XEventArgs` and `IXViewModel` types are not really important, the former is used to transfer information when the respective event is fired and the latter, to allow flexibility so you can use the `SubtitleHandler` with absolutely any sort of Controls, MediaElement, etc.

Comment: Doesn't that declaration: `Func<ObservableMap<TEnumeration, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>>, MediaEventArgs<TEnumeration>, TEnumeration>` bother you? :)

Comment: It does indeed.. @NikitaB